# Error: Incorrect number of dimensions in correlation plot with significance test in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, correlation

I create a correlation plot with this code:

```
require(ggpubr)
require(tidyverse)
require(Hmisc)

M = mydata % > %
    select(var1, var2, var3, var4)
    corrplot(cor(select_if(M, is.numeric)), method = "ellipse", type = "upper", col = c("black", "white"),
    bg = "lightblue", tl.col = "black")
```

I would like to add a significance test as described on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html:

```
res1 < -cor.mtest(mydata, conf.level = .95)

M = mydata % > %
    select(var1, var2, var3, var4)
    corrplot(cor(select_if(M, is.numeric)), method = "ellipse", type = "upper", col = c("black", "white"),
    bg = "lightblue", tl.col = "black", p.mat = res1$p, sig.level = .05)
```

But this doesn't work, I get this error message:

> ERROR in ind[, 2] : incorrect number of dimensions

What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a reproducible example, it is difficult to be sure what is your problem here.

However, my intuition is that your `res1` output have made the correlation test on the entire dataframe `mydata` whereas you are trying to get the correlation plot of few variables (var1 to var4).

So, that could explain the error message because you are calling `res1$p` that have probable more dimensions than the portion of `mydata` you are trying to plot.

Does `mydata` has only 4 variables ? or more ?

Instead try:

```r
res1 < -cor.mtest(mydata[,c("var1", "var2", "var3", "var4")], conf.level = .95)

M = mydata % > %
    select(var1, var2, var3, var4)
    corrplot(cor(select_if(M, is.numeric)), method = "ellipse", type = "upper", col = c("black", "white"),
    bg = "lightblue", tl.col = "black", p.mat = res1$p, sig.level = .05)
```

If this is not working, please consider providing a reproducible example of `mydata` (see this tutorial to know how to provide a reproducible example: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example))